# Redux and Axios get. method not returning any data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

Need some help.
As I am trying to get some understanding of React/REdux global state I made some simple get request.
This is done with Axios, thunk, Redux, but i can't get this working

I have Post.js file, nothing fancy

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import PostForm from './PostForm';

export class Post extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    posts: PropTypes.any,
    fetchPosts: PropTypes.func,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchPosts } = this.props;
    fetchPosts();
  }


  render() {
    const { posts } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <PostForm addPost={this.onSubmit} />
        <br />
        <div>
          {posts.map(post => (
            <div key={post.id}>
              <h3>{post.title}</h3>
              <p>{post.body}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Post;
```

Next i have my PostContainer.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Post from './Post';
import { fetchFromApi } from '../reducers/postReducers';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  posts: state.posts,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchPosts: () => dispatch(fetchFromApi()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Post);
```

My reducer

```
import Axios from 'axios';

/* action type */

const FETCH_POSTS = 'FETCH_POSTS';

/* action creator */
export const fetchStarted = payload => ({ payload, type: FETCH_POSTS });

/* thunk */
export const fetchFromApi = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    Axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=5').then(res =>
      dispatch(fetchStarted(res.data))
    );
  };
};

/* reducer */
export default function reducer(state = [], action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_POSTS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload,
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and my store

```
import { combineReducers, applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

import postReducer from './reducers/postReducers';

const initialState = {
  posts: {
    data: {},
  },
};

const reducers = {
  posts: postReducer,
};

Object.keys(initialState).forEach(item => {
  if (typeof reducers[item] == 'undefined') {
    reducers[item] = (state = null) => state;
  }
});

const combinedReducers = combineReducers(reducers);

const store = createStore(
  combinedReducers,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export default store;
```

All of that is doing not much. My map method is trying to map empty posts object. And for some reason my fetchPosts is not dispatched. I have reade some old posts here but still can't get this working

Thanks

Edit
this is my app.js file with container

```
import React from 'react';

import './App.css';
import Post from './components/PostContainer';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div className='App'>
        <Post />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The initial state of your posts reducer is an array `state = []` which makes sense, but then you update it to an object with a `data` property. `{ ...state, data: action.payload }`.

Comment: okay. So what do you suggest?

Comment: `return action.payload`? Keep the state as an array.

Comment: This is not working :/. This was one of my many failed attempts
```Cannot read property 'map' of undefined```

Comment: Where are you rendering the `Post` component? Are you correctly important the `PostContainer` instead?

Comment: just added the App.js where i have <Post /> from postconatiner

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working.

Data was not there when my posts array was render. After passing simple if statemante all is working